# MySQL server has gone away - shared account

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to do the following but keep getting "MySQL server has gone away"

1. Read approx 100,000 rows from an informix db (each row approx 400 chars). **No issues with this**
2. Insert the 100,000 rows into a MySQL table hosted on shared hostgator acct

I received "MySQL server has gone away" and then updated my `INSERT` to use one `INSERT command`

Ex: `$queryMySQL = INSERT into table (field1, field2, field3,...) values ('A', '2017-02-01', ..), ('B', '2017-02-01', ..),  ('C', '2017-02-01', ...),...'`

This didn't work so I tried opening a persistant connection
`ini_set('mysqli.reconnect', 'on')`; and `$db_mysqli = new mysqli('p:'.$host, $Username,$Pswd,$database);`

This didn't help so I tried inserting 50,000 instead of 100,000 (which i prefer not to do) but still get `MySQL server has gone away`

Since this is a shared hostgator account, I don't have access to `php.ini` nor `mysql.cnf`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Pay for decent hosting :P

Comment: If you're taking up a lot of resources in MySQL, then it will just cut off your connection (hence 'MySQL has gone away'). You need to slow it down, maybe put some sleeps in there, so MySQL has the time to process your requests.

Comment: What happens if you try to perform insert one row at a time? If you try to insert many rows at once, you may be hitting a server timeout.

Comment: There's usually a limit on how many rows you can instert with a single MySQL query, maybe 100 or 1000 (not sure) try splitting it up into multiple inserts.

Comment: have you verified **max_allowed_packet** like this  **SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';** see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/

Answer (score 0):

**Why it happened**

> You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that
>   is incorrect or too large. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large.
>   or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the
>   client and closes the connection.

**What can be done**

> The easy way to avoid this problem is to ensure that
>   max_allowed_packet is set bigger in the mysqld server than in the
>   client and that all clients uses the same value for
>   max_allowed_packet.

**What you can do??**

Since you're already using a hosting, ask the hosting support to fix the issue. Well if they cannot and you can reduce the query size reduce it, and if it doesn't solve your issue, trying changing the hosting.

[MYSQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: I ended up creating  an array and each element consists of an "INSERT" of 1,000 rows.   Then loop through the array and for each element 1) open connection, 2)  `$db_mysqli->query($queryInserts($i))`, 3) close connection.

Comment: Yea, that seems logical